# Скачивание файлов с сайта

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, хочу на сайте сделать файловый архив. 
Загружаю файлы скриптом:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input name="add" type="file" />
    <input name="save" type="submit" value="Сохранить" />
    </form>
    <?
     if(isset($_FILES["add"])) 
{ 
$myfile = $_FILES["add"]["tmp_name"]; 
$myfile_name = $_FILES["add"]["name"]; 
$myfile_size = $_FILES["add"]["size"]; 
$myfile_type = $_FILES["add"]["type"]; 
$error_flag = $_FILES["add"]["error"];

// Если ошибок не было 
if($error_flag == 0) 
{

$upload='./my_files/' . $myfile_name;

 copy($_FILES['add']['tmp_name'], $upload);

print("Имя файла на нашем сервере (во время запроса): ".$myfile."<br>"); 
print("Имя файла на компьютере пользователя: ".$myfile_name."<br>");
print("Имя файла на сервере: ".$f."<br>");
print("MIME-тип файла: ".$myfile_type."<br>"); 
print("Размер файла: ".$myfile_size."<br><br>"); 
}
}
$dir = "./my_files/";
$files = scandir($dir);
?>
<form action="download.php" method="POST"  >
<?
foreach ($files as $n_files)
{
    ?>
    <input name="file" type="radio" value="<?php echo $n_files; ?>">
    <?
    echo $n_files . '<br>';

}
    ?>
    <input name="download" type="submit" value="Сохранить" />
    </form>
    <?
?>
```

А это скрипт скачивания:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['file']))
{

     $file = $_POST['file'];     
}
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file.'');
?>
```

Проблема в том, что при скачивании любых файлов расширение файла игнорируеться. Подскажите, как сделать, чтоб скачивалось с расширением файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
//или
header('Content-type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file.'');
```

Comment: пробовал, файл без расширения

Answer (score 0):

if($error_flag == 0)

вообще, есть $_FILES['uploadfile']['error'] - Код ошибки, которая может возникнуть при загрузке файла.

А по остальному - ответ от [@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan)

Comment: загружаеться файл на сайт все в порядке, а вот скачиваеться...

Comment: тоесть в папку

Comment: да, еще файл с русскими символами нельзя?

Comment: Имена в БД храните, если русских букавок хотите. иначе пока что никак.

Comment: вся проблема была в пробелах в имени файла